# QGIS Open Street Map plugin metadata

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins, metadata

I am trying to use an old map I made in QGIS which has a base map from Open Street Map (OSM)
To credit OSM in my paper/chapter I need to find the date or at least the year of the OSM data,

OSM wiki says I should credit it like this in the references:

OpenStreetMap contributors. (2015) Planet dump [Data file from $date of database dump$]. Retrieved from https://planet.openstreetmap.org

My problem is I don't know $date  of database dump$

Is there an easy way to find this? I haven't used QGIS for the past couple of years and I've spent an hour on it but the metadata seems to be empty and I can't find anything online yet on how to find it. I assume there must be a way to reimport OSM data and check the data of the data imported.  (New data is fine, I don't necessarily need to use a base map from 2 years ago), but I will still have the problem that the date/metadata may not be being imported or I don't know how to find it. Does anyone know an easy way, or where to click to see the date/OSM metadata?

Comment: Did you import the OSM planet file into your own PostGIS and then rendered your own basemap?

Comment: @user30184 I can't remember what I did sorry, since it was two years ago I'll have to look up how to do it and try again. I think I just used the plugin that is in QGIS rather than anything tricky. I'll have a go at attempting to recreate the map later next week and get back to you (assuming my question isn't closed in the meantime :( ) (I have something due Tues and after that will get back to this), thanks for your reply!

Comment: If you used the QGIS plugin then you have not downloaded and imported the OSM planet file and page https://planet.openstreetmap.org/ is not relevant for you. The page about interactive maps and static maps is better https://osmfoundation.org/wiki/Licence/Attribution_Guidelines#Static_images. If your maps were created two years ago then using something like "Map data from OpenStreetMap 2021" should be OK.

Comment: @user30184 ah, ok, thank you very much, that's great!! much simpler.  If you want to put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: If You put that as an answer I'll accept it. You need reputation more than I do.

Comment: @user30184 haha very true, though really just happy with being able to get the referencing right, and will be much faster in the future too. So was worth asking even if I lost reputation for it. -thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood OpenStreetMap referencing, in case anyone else does the same and it helps:

As noted by user30184:

If you used the QGIS plugin then you have not downloaded and imported the OSM planet file and page planet.openstreetmap.org is not relevant for you. The page about interactive maps and static maps is better https://osmfoundation.org/wiki/Licence/Attribution_Guidelines#Static_images
If your maps were created two years ago then using something like "Map data from OpenStreetMap 2021" should be OK